# CDF embedding in HTML

Tags: cdf-format, html

I created a working CDF file on my Mac, and I am trying to embed it into an html page, and although I followed all the steps suggested on the mathematica web embedding page, it is not working (I always get a white page when I try to open my page). This is what I have done so far:

- I exported my *Mathematica* code as a CDF standalone "AGN-standaloneClear.cdf", checked and it is working with CDF Player
- I opened TextEdit, converted to plain text and wrote:

  ```
  <html>
  <body>
  <embed src="AGN-standaloneClear.cdf” width=“1380” height=“6792”>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

and saved it as test.html into the same folder where the cdf is.

When I try to open it with Chrome the page is completely white however, and if I try to reopen the test.html file it is completely white. I never tried to deal with html, so I think I could be doing some very noob errors that are not even explained in the guides I read so far, but however I don't know what to do.

-EDIT-

Here is the code that generates the white page:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/plugin/v2.1/cdfplugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var cdf = new cdfplugin();
cdf.setDefaultContent('<a href="http://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/"><img  src="prova.png"></a>');
cdf.embed('AGNstandaloneClear.cdf', 1380, 6792);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the one that generates the cropped cdf (http://postimg.org/image/tgqa3bicl/):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/plugin/v2.1/cdfplugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var cdf = new cdfplugin();
cdf.setDefaultContent('<a href="http://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/"><img  src="prova.png"></a>');
cdf.embed('AGNstandaloneClear.cdf', 435, 325);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When working with code/HTML, remember to disengage "smart quotes" (like the ones around the `width` value)- they sometimes cause problems.

Comment: it is loading the cdf now, thanks. however it is not loading correctly, it is cropped, like if the width and height values are not correcte. however if I modufy height and width values to the correct ones i get the white page again

Comment: You should continue to update your question with more information - perhaps someone can see the problem then...

Comment: I don't know what informations can I give more... this is the snapshot of how it looks after I modified the cose as cormullion suggested:

http://postimg.org/image/tgqa3bicl/

Comment: 6792 seems very large for a web page - my browser window is only 1000 x 1000. But it worked for me (once I'd scrolled the page enough).

Comment: It works now, as you said 6792 was too high (although it was the size suggested by mathematica). I tried reducing the until the browser finally visualized my cdf correctly

Comment: Did you select the Manipulate (?) window before running the wizard. Perhaps Mathematica is trying to include the whole document. Anyway, you've got it working, cool...

Comment: No I didn't, I wanted to export the whole document, not just one of the manipulate windows.
anyway thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: It is really VERY simple to put CDF in HTML. No need for javascript, just use the line you showed, <embed src="AGN-standaloneClear.cdf" width="1380" height="6792"> All what you have to do is manually adjust the width value and the height value to your liking. That is what I do. I set it at width="700" height="700" and see if this showed the whole Manipulate or not. If not, I adjust the numbers. It only takes one or 2 tries to get the right numbers you want. This is how I have been adding CDF's to my pages for a very long time, never had a problem. Save CDF as standalone and all document.

Answer (score 3):

This HTML code works for me:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/plugin/v2.1/cdfplugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var cdf = new cdfplugin();
cdf.setDefaultContent('<a href="http://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/"><img  src="test-embed.png"></a>');
cdf.embed('test-embed.cdf', 435, 325);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The `<script>` sections were generated by Mathematica version 9.0.1 command **File>CDF Export>Web Embeddable**.

Comment: What browser is supported I cannot open `http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/test.html` with chrome, Firefox or opera on a fedora 64 bit machine